# Some Russian letters overlap the next line of text when used in drop caps

Tags: lettrine, drop-cap

An author I am working with requires typesettng of their work as follows, but the Russian letters used in some of the drop caps overlap the 4th line. I tried plaing as per the comments in the below MWE, but could not go below the height achieved by its current state. How can I reduce the drop cap font size a little bit to remove the slight overlap?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{gentium} % required by the author

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.17} % required by the author
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[main=russian]{babel}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{type1cm}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\setcounter{DefaultLines}{3}
\renewcommand{\DefaultLoversize}{0.01} % tried playing with values from 0.0001 to 0.14
\renewcommand{\LettrineTextFont}{}
\setlength{\DefaultFindent}{\fontdimen2\font}

\begin{document}
\lettrine[]{Д}{} \lipsum[1]
\lettrine[]{Щ}{} \lipsum[2]
\lettrine[]{Ц}{} \lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

`memoir` has integrated `lettrine` package. it can be used in text for example as `\versal{Д}{}\lipsum[66]` which gives the same result as `\lettrine[]{Д}{}` from `letttrine` package.

a dirty hack, which lift letters in `\versal` for small amount, is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{gentium} % required by the author

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.17} % required by the author
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[main=russian]{babel}
\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{type1cm}
\newlength{\versaldepth}
\setlength{\versaldepth}{1.17\baselineskip}
\newcommand{\versal}[2]{{\noindent
    \setbox0\hbox{%
        \fontsize{3\versaldepth}{3.2\versaldepth}\selectfont #1}%
    \count0=\ht0                   % height of versal
    \count1=\baselineskip          % baselineskip
    \divide\count0 by \count1      % versal height/baselineskip
    \dimen1 = \count0\baselineskip % distance to drop versal
    \advance\count0 by 1\relax     % no of indented lines
    \dimen0=\wd0                   % width of versal
    \global\hangindent\dimen0      % set indentation distance
    \global\hangafter-\count0      % set no of indented lines
    \hskip-\dimen0\setbox0\hbox to\dimen0{\raise-\dimexpr-4pt+\dimen1\box0\hss}%
    \dp0=0in\ht0=0in\box0}
    }

\begin{document}
\versal{Д}{}\lipsum[66]

\versal{Щ}{}\lipsum[66]

\versal{Ц}{}\lipsum[66]

\versal{B}{}\lipsum[66]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `loversize=-0.1` and a positive value to `lraise`.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{gentium} % required by the author

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[main=russian]{babel}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{lettrine}

\setcounter{DefaultLines}{3}
\renewcommand{\DefaultLoversize}{-0.1}
\renewcommand{\DefaultLraise}{0.15}
\renewcommand{\LettrineTextFont}{}
\setlength{\DefaultFindent}{\fontdimen2\font}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.17} % required by the author

\begin{document}
\lettrine{Д}{} \lipsum[1]
\lettrine{Щ}{} \lipsum[2]
\lettrine{Ц}{} \lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]